# Cooler query based on temperature(>85°C)

Tags: cpu-cooler

Yesterday I played watch dogs 2 for 1hr,and the temperature of the i7-4790 rose to >85°C,as reported by afterburner and hwinfo.My doubt is if the cooler made improper contact with CPU,would not the pc freeze or restart..after gaming for 1 hr?Please clear my doubt and I dont play long hrs,so stock cooler would do fine.Thx for clearing my doubt

Answer (score 1):

Most modern CPUs will start to throttle back when they meet their temperature so you will actually see a drop in performance rather than crashes or reboots.

Intel specifically state that the [maximum CPU case temperature​](http://ark.intel.com/products/80806/Intel-Core-i7-4790-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_00-GHz) is 72°C, but the core temperature will be a lot hotter than this. The internet suggests the maximum temperature you will measure using software is 90°C: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2210400/4790k-temperatures.html

You may want to check your cooler and replace your thermal paste as for long term reliability cooler temperatures are always better but unless it has been limiting performance or crashing you are okay.

Comment: A little confused after reading this : http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1761301/brand-cpu-overheating-issue.html

Comment: Confused how exactly? They are stating that it got to 100°C which is too hot and were advised to recheck their cooler, in particular to check that there isn't a plastic cover between the thermal material on the heatsink and the CPU. Anything below 90 might be okay, below 80 should be fine, below 70 is good and below 60 is great. Check that you have good airflow around your case.

Comment: Confused as it frooze,crashed

Comment: They *should* throttle back to cool down, but if the cooling is nowhere near good enough or is impeded by lack of airflow or plastic in the way then throttling may not be enough and the temperature will still rise above safe temperatures. At that point it will simply "fail" and crash.

Comment: I got this computer all assembled and there aren't any techies around here,nearby.So as the chassis plate is obstructing to check the mobo's back,how do I ensure stock cooler is properly seated.I am newbie and looking at the push pins does not give a clear idea.